# Asymptotic Notation difference

Tags: time-complexity, runtime

Is O(2<sup>n</sup>) same as 2<sup>O(n)</sup>? If yes, how can I claim it or it is obvious?

> O represents Big O

Comment: guess you should post th question in the mathematics community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not the same. If it were true, we would have for example `2^(2n) ∈ O(2^n)`. In other words, there exists a `k` such that `k 2^n` dominates `2^(2n)`.

But for every `k`, we have that

```
k 2^n < 2^(2n)
```

for all `n > log2(k)`.

Therefore, `2^(2n) ∉ O(2^n)`.

Comment: If N = log n, can we say that O(sqrt(n)) = 2^O(N)?

Comment: No, you can't say that.